# Show that the $\limsup$ is the supremum of the set of limit points

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence of real numbers and let E be the set of limit points. Is it the case that $\limsup a_{n} = \sup E$.

Attempt:

My initial answer is yes, if I start with the simpler case of $a_{n}$ being a bounded sequnece of real numbers, let $b_{n}:=\sup\{a_{k}:k\geq n\}$ then since $b_{n}$ converges, every subsequence will converge to the same limit. Let $(a_{n_{k}})$ be a convergent subsequence. Then we have $a_{n_{k}} \leq b_{n_{k}}$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Taking limits the we get $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_{n_{k}} \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty}a_{n}$.

I don't think the same argument will work if the sequence is unbounded? (Corrected thanks to Steven Stadnicki)

Comment: I presume your last question means 'if the sequence is unbounded'; for the definition to make sense, though, you have to consider $\infty$ to be a valid limit point (e.g., it is a limit point of the sequence $a_n$ that alternates between 0 and $n$ based on the parity of $n$; i.e., $a_n=\{0,2,0,4,0,6,\ldots\}$).

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Yes, unbounded, will correct the typo. Yes, agree about the infinity point, but isn't that the general convention anyway, since people say the limsup always exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unbounded case is relatively straightforward: since we have $\limsup a_n=\infty$, for each $M$ and each $n_0$ there's some $n\geq n_0$ with $a_n\geq M$. Define a sequence $b_i$ such that $b_i$ is the first number $\gt b_{i-1}$ such that $a_{b_i}\geq i$, and note that this defines a subsequence of $a_n$ whose limit is $\infty$.